# unexpected end of data data = JSON.parse(errorThrown.responseText);

Tags: jquery

i have the following script. On error it works by showing a modal I have tested this and it works. On success it should display an alert box, but I get the message:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
```

Here is the line throwing the error:

```
data = JSON.parse(errorThrown.responseText);
```

However, it should not be running this on success right?

Could someone take a look?

The page returns `201 CREATED` on success as it should.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/accounts/create/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
    },
    data: $('#registration').serialize(),
    success: function () {
        console.log('success');
        alert("test")
    },
    error: function (errorThrown) {
        data = JSON.parse(errorThrown.responseText);
        $('#account-error').modal("show");
        $('#error-text').html(data.error);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: `errorThrown.responseText` is not JSON formatted and cannot be parsed.

Comment: What's the value of `errorThrown.responseText`?

Comment: errorThrown does not have 'responseText' field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the dataType. The error will be json but it looks like your success dataType is not. This means it triggers the 'error' function again. Just remove the dataType and see what happens.

Comment: Damn, said it in comments 1 min after him, FML :|

Answer (score 0):

The data your are trying to parse as JSON is not [JSON formatted](http://www.json.org/).

You may use

`if(typeof jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText)==="object")`

to detect if the response text is in a valid JSON format!

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

You might want to try using [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
var ajaxRequest = jQuery.post("/accounts/create/", $('#registration').serialize(), function() {
  //On success
})
  .fail(function(errorThrown) {
    data = errorThrown.responseText;
    $('#account-error').modal("show");
    $('#error-text').html(data.error);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });
```

You are trying to JSON parse a Javascript Object, when you specify the dataType in the ajax request, the response is already converted from Json to a Javascript object.

Comment: so what you are saying is the function error: function(errorThrown)  also runs on success?

Comment: @User7 It appears to be the case since that function runs... Also, there is no need to reinvent the wheel by using using `jQuery.ajax` when `jQuery.post` is available. I edited my answer to show just that.

Comment: @User7 I didnt notice it but you were trying to JSON parse a JAvascript object, edited my answer... Sorry for the brain fart...